# Can't use createRoot with typeScript - "TypeError: m.createRoot is not a function"

Tags: typescript, leaflet, typeerror, react-18

I'm working on a project using React 18 and Leaflet. (I don't believe Leaflet is part of the problem but it might be worth mentioning.) I'm trying to add custom elements to the map, but using createRoot gives me `TypeError: m.createRoot is not a function`.
The code sample of what i'm trying to use is here:

```
import { MutableRefObject, ReactElement, useEffect } from 'react'

import L, { Map } from 'leaflet'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

interface MapControlElementProps {
    mapRef: MutableRefObject<Map | null>
    button: ReactElement
    position: L.ControlPosition
}

export default function TestElement(props: MapControlElementProps) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const { mapRef, button, position } = props
        if (mapRef.current) {
            const MapHelp = L.Control.extend({
                onAdd: () => {
                    const controlElement = L.DomUtil.create(
                        'div',
                        'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'
                    )
                    const root = createRoot(controlElement)
                    root.render(button)
                    return controlElement
                },
            })
            const control = new MapHelp({ position })
            control.addTo(mapRef.current)
            return () => {
                control.remove()
            }
        }
        return () => {}
    }, [props])

    return null
}
```

The only thing that works is using

```
ReactDOM.render(button, controlElement)
```

But tests are complaining about that:

```
Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot
```

Although ReactDOM.render works, I would much prefer to use createRoot because i'm using 18 everywhere else.

**Update to the situation 2nd of March 2023**

So far i have tracked the issue to react-dom package, react-dom/client.js where there is this code:

```
'use strict';

var m = require('react-dom');
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  exports.createRoot = m.createRoot;
  exports.hydrateRoot = m.hydrateRoot;
} else {
  var i = m.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED;
  exports.createRoot = function(c, o) {
    i.usingClientEntryPoint = true;
    try {
      return m.createRoot(c, o);
    } finally {
      i.usingClientEntryPoint = false;
    }
  };
  exports.hydrateRoot = function(c, h, o) {
    i.usingClientEntryPoint = true;
    try {
      return m.hydrateRoot(c, h, o);
    } finally {
      i.usingClientEntryPoint = false;
    }
  };
}
```

First of all, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED seems like an odd choice for name if this was indeed meant to be published but what do i know. However, a bit of poking around shows me that var m indeed doesn't have a function called createRoot. What to do with this now, i still don't know.

Comment: Your code doesn’t appear to reference the error you quoted.

Comment: Did you try updating `@types/react` to `18.x`?

Comment: Types have been updated, currently 18.0.10 but no help.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue while upgrading our app from React 17 to React 18.The app was originally created `using create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

Error:

```
TypeError: m.createRoot is not a function
```

The fix for me is to update the `index.html` to use react 18 scripts instead of earlier react 17. Basically, this makes sense as react couldn't find the definition of `createRoot` in react 17 scripts and able to read the definition when updated to use react 18 scripts.

Before: when using react 17

```
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>            
 <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

after the upgrade/ **to resolve the issue**: when using react 18

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This should have been included in the react upgrade documentation but at the time of this response I couldn't find it and couldn't find any help elsewhere. Hopefully this will help someone :)

References:

- [minify-javascript-for-production](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#tip-minify-javascript-for-production)
- [react-18-upgrade-guide](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide)